# PHP 7.3 A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php, line, warnings

I have an error in my PHP 7.3 and it refers to a line of code which is:

```
if (!is_int($Key) || $Key != $LastKey + 1)
```

The exact error is Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /my/filename.php

Comment: care to share values of `$Key` and `$LastKey`?

Comment: Check what is `$LastKey` and `$Key`

Comment: Did this code run without an error in an earlier PHP version? Just wondering because you specified PHP 7.3.

Comment: It was 7.1 that introduced that warning for mathematical operations - the only bit of this code that would raise it is if `$LastKey` isn't numeric. See https://3v4l.org/csre0